# The multiple DELETE in mysql did not delete the records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:  table1 and table1_details (id is PK and table1.id=table1_details.id ). I write the multiple DELETE sql to delete the relevant records:

```
delete a, b from table1 a, table1_details b where a.id=9 or b.t1_id =9
```

However it did not delete the record. ( table1 has a record where id=9, table1_details has no records where id=9 )

what's the problem?

Comment: What is the actual join logic here?  Currently, you're joining based on the `id` in either table being 9.  Is that what you want?  You should consider switching to modern join syntax.

Comment: table1 has a column id which is PK, table1_details  has a column id which is PK and a column t1_id which is equals table1 's id.  The multiple DELETE sql runs without error, but did not delete any record

Comment: if i write: delete a, b from table1 a, table1_details b where a.id=9 and a.id=b.t1_id  .. it did not delete any record neither.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table1_details b ON a.id = 9 OR b.t1_id = 9` <-- does this query return any records?

Comment: i found the problem. It is because table1_details doesnt have the records match with t1_id = 9.  If i add a record in table1_details where t1_id = 9. the multiple DELETE sql works and it will delete the relevant records in 2 tables.  So do I have to write delete sql seperately for this scenario?

Comment: I think a delete join will only work on both tables if you connect them via the join.  So, you might have to write separate delete statements here (which is certainly not the worst thing in the world to do).  Also, looking into `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which might also help here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think i wrote the wrong format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the wrong format. it should be

```
delete a, b from table1 a left JOIN table1_details b on a.id=b.t1_id where a.id=9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete table1,table1_details from table1 a join table1_details b on table1.id=table1_details.t1_id where a.id=9
```

run this query it will delete from both tables